# Updating all tables with null dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I was helped out with this select query that I am using to get all tables with null values in two columns

```
select count(*)
from (
   select LastModifiedDate from Table1
      union all
   select LastModifiedDate from Table2
      union all
   select LastModifiedDate from Table3
) a 
where LastModifiedDate is null
```

To update all three tables is there a better way to do it then

```
Update table1
SET LastModifiedDate = GETDATE()
WHERE LastModifiedDate is null

Update table2
SET LastModifiedDate = GETDATE()
WHERE LastModifiedDate is null
```

and so on?
Sorry I split the query's one looks for CreationDate and one looks for LastModifiedDate

Comment: You want to change both dates, even when only one is NULL?  You may be writing over a lot of valid creation dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way. As Gordon Linoff noted in the comments, you might overwrite valid created dates with your proposed query.

Try this instead:

```
Update table1
SET CreationDate = ISNULL(CreationDate,GETDATE())
  , LastModifiedDate = GETDATE()
WHERE CreationDate is null or LastModifiedDate is null

Update table2
SET CreationDate = ISNULL(CreationDate,GETDATE())
  , LastModifiedDate = GETDATE()
WHERE CreationDate is null or LastModifiedDate is null

Update table3
SET CreationDate = ISNULL(CreationDate,GETDATE())
  , LastModifiedDate = GETDATE()
WHERE CreationDate is null or LastModifiedDate is null
```

Using `ISNULL` will preserve existing `CreationDate` data. You don't want to use it for `LastModifiedDate`, because you're going to be modifying the rows, so that value should change.

However, there's no reason to try and restructure your statements, as there's nothing wrong with them.

Answer (score 0):

You want to update three tables, setting two columns to the current date time if either of those columns are NULL.

Three table update statements will do the trick.  It doesn't get any simpler than that.